# Use only list/collection to store data locally on webpage

Tags: c#, generic-collections

I'm getting only 1 record using this code, but i want to display multiple records on page. I have 3 columns to display on page which are: `id`,`name` and `lastname`.
How can I get this done?

Code Behind:

```
protected List<Class1> GetClass1()
{
    Class1 uinfo = new Class1();
    uinfo.ID = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text);
    uinfo.Name = TextBox2.Text;
    uinfo.LastName = TextBox3.Text;
    data.Add(uinfo);
    return data;   
}

protected void BindUserDetails()
{
    data = GetClass1();
    GridView1.DataSource = data;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Class file:

```
public class Class1
{
    Int16 id;
    string name = string.Empty;
    string lastname = string.Empty;

    public Int16 ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have more than one group of TextBoxes on your form? from this code, one record would be expected, since you are reading directly from 3 text boxes on the page into 3 properties in a single class instance....

Comment: Yes that's what i want to do. #Elegant Coder

Comment: I don't have any other group. #Andrew Counts

Comment: i don't want to store data permanently.....can't you do some help with coding.#Elegant Coder

Comment: Quick tip, if you want to comment on someones comment use: @desiredusername ;)

Comment: @deeppatel : Please let me know the actual scenario. Are you trying to bind the data to a datalist or gridview or something like that??

Comment: @ElegantCoder :gridview it is.

Comment: One piece of information that is missing here is where `GetClass1` is called.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper :BindUserDetails() method.i jst add that in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one solution for you. This is just a sample implementation. Please modify according your requirement.

The Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BindingListSample
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static List<Employee> bindingL = new List<Employee>();
        protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindingL.Add(new Employee { Name = TxtName.Text });
            GrvSample.DataSource = bindingL;
            GrvSample.DataBind();
        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that you need to use static with your list. When you use static you can store the values that you have inserted until the application is closed. Refer Static Keyword for more explanation.

This is just my way to tackle this situation.

Hope This Helps

Comment: @ Elegant Coder: How to DELETE a record?

Comment: @deeppatel : Should be a different question i guess.. And probably a google search first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 `List<Class1> data = new List<Class1>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        if (Session["test"] != null)
        {
            data = Session["test"] as List<Class1>;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 cl = new Class1 { ID = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text), Name = TextBox2.Text, LastName = TextBox3.Text };
        data.Add(cl);            
        Session["test"] = data;

        dataBind();
    }

    protected void dataBind()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = data;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}`